Integral convolution equation $\int_{B_n(R) } e^{- \| x - t\|} d\nu(t) = e^{- \|x \|^2/2}$ on $x \in B_n(R)$. Find measure $\nu$
Let $B_n(R)$ denote the $n$ ball centered at zero with radius $R$.  We are interested in the following integral equation: given $R>0$ and $\lambda>0$, let
\begin{align}
\int_{B_n(R)} e^{- \lambda \| x -t\|} d \nu(t) = C_n e^{- \frac{\| x\|^2}{2}}, \,  \forall x \in B_n(R),
\end{align}
where $\nu$ is a bounded real-valued measure supported on $B_n(R)$ (it will be clear soon why we take measure theoretic approach) and $C_n$ is the normalization constant — we can absorb it into $\nu$.
We are interested in finding $\nu$ that satisfies this equation. The difficulty is the second ball constraint, which makes the application of the Fourier transform difficult.
It appears to me that the solution, which I cannot find, has the following properties:

$\nu$ is spherically symmetric
$\nu$ can be decomposed into two parts
\begin{align}
\nu = \nu_c + \nu_R
\end{align}
where $\nu_c$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure and $\nu_R$ is uniformly supported on the boundary of $B_n(R)$.

One can think about this problem radially. In this case $\nu_R$ is delta function at $R$.
I don't think $\nu_c$ is always a positive measure, so the bonus would be to find when it is positive.
Here are more concrete questions that I don't know how to answer rigorously:

How to show that $\nu_R$ is indeed there? In other, words how to show that a solution has to decompose as $\nu= \nu_c + \nu_R$  ( If we can that it's there showing that it is uniformly supported is not difficult)
(Optional) Characterize $\lambda$ and $R$ such that $\nu_c$ is a non-negative measure?

I also feel something like this might have appeared in physics literature, but could not find anything. References would also be appreciated.

One could change variables so that $B_n$ becomes $\mathbb R^n$ (for example, $t= x/|x| \tan 2|x|/(\pi R)$), and then taking Fourier transforms will make a product out the convolution. There are technical issues since the functions are only bounded, so the FTs are distributions.

@ChristianRemling Could you just add a bit more details how this would look like? Anyway, just trying to document your thought process. Thanks

@ChristianRemling Quick question. Do you want to change the range of integration or the outside constraint?

The transformation I suggested changes the region of integration automatically (to $\mathbb R^n$).

Not sure if this is interesting, but here is the answer in dimension $n = 1$. It should perhaps be a comment, not an answer, but it is way too long. Needless to say, this method does not apply in higher dimensions.

Write $f(x) = e^{-x^2/2}$ and $g(x) = e^{-\lambda |x|}$, so that our convolution equation becomes $$\nu * g = f \qquad \text{in } (-R, R).$$ Observe that $$\lambda g - \lambda^{-1} g'' = \delta_0.$$ Therefore, in $(-R, R)$ we necessarily have $$\nu = \nu * \delta_0 = \lambda \nu * g - \lambda^{-1} (\nu * g)'' = \lambda f - \lambda^{-1} f''.$$ Thus, $\nu$ is absolutely continuous in $(-R, R)$, with density $$\rho = \lambda f - \lambda^{-1} f''.$$
Additionally, $\nu$ may have an atom at $\pm R$. In order to evaluate its mass, we may observe that $\rho * g = f$ on $\mathbb R$, so that for $x \in (-R, R)$ we have
$$ \begin{aligned}
  f(x) & = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x - t) \rho(t) dt \\
  & = \int_{-R}^R g(x - t) \rho(t) dt + \int_{-\infty}^{-R} g(x - t) \rho(t) dt + \int_R^\infty g(x - t) \rho(t) dt .
\end{aligned} $$
However, for $t < -R$ we have $g(x - t) = e^{-\lambda x + \lambda t} = e^{\lambda (t + R)} g(x + R)$, and hence
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{-R} g(x - t) \rho(t) dt = g(x + R) \int_{-\infty}^{-R} e^{\lambda (t + R)} \rho(t) dt = \alpha g(x + R) . $$
In the same vein,
$$ \int_R^\infty g(x - t) \rho(t) dt = \alpha g(x - R) . $$

It follows that $\nu * g = f$ in $(-R, R)$ if
$$ \nu(dx) = \rho(x) \mathbb{1}_{(-R, R)}(x) dx + \alpha (\delta_{-R}(dx) + \delta_R(dx)) , $$
where
$$ \rho(x) = \lambda (2 - x^2) e^{-x^2/2} $$
and, using Mathematica,
$$ \alpha = e^{-R^2/2} \Bigl(\lambda (\lambda - R) + \sqrt{\tfrac{\pi}{2}} \lambda^3 e^{(\lambda + R^2)/2} \bigl(1 - \operatorname{erf}(\tfrac{\lambda + R}{\sqrt{2}})\bigr) \Bigr) . $$

Thanks. I was also able to find a solution for $n=1$, but through a more  'convoluted' approach.   This trick with derivatives of Laplace is quite nice.

Mateusz, I ask just to understand since I am surely missing somenthing: why is this 1-dim solution not the general one? Given that both the kernel and the known second side are radially symmetric, why we cannot assume that $\nu(t)=\nu(|t|)$, pass to polar coordinates and solve a 1d problem?

@DanieleTampieri: In higher dimensions, I think every single piece of the above calculation is just wrong. To be specific: (a) $g(x) = exp(-\lambda|x|)$ is no longer the fundamental solution for a constant coefficient second order differential operator; (b) $g(x+t)=g(x)g(t)$ is no longer true; (c) after rewriting things in terms of radial functions, the problem is no longer a convolution equation.
